# render the image from the array of array in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

I am new to the react js. Here I am getting the following data .

data is the array which has some elements .

```
data[22] elements .
  images [4]:
     1
     2
     3
     4
```

so structure is like this. I tried with the following apporch

```
let images = data.map(image => {
       image.map(imgId => {
         return <img src={imgId.source} alr="" />
       })
   });
```

can any one help me with this ?>

Comment: can you please post you json data

Answer (score 0):

If Images is array of data

```
<div>
 {data.Images.map(image =>
   return <img src={image.source} alt="my-img" />
 )}
</div>
```

Comment: But in the data there are different elements. for every element there is a diff images array .

Comment: @ganeshkaspate please post json

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you mean, but in your code, you missed `return` in the first `map` function. You can write into this:

```
let images = data.map(image => {
       return image.map(imgId => {
         return <img src={imgId.source} alr="" />
       })
   });
```

or

```
let images = data.map(image => (
       image.map(imgId => {
         return <img src={imgId.source} alr="" />
       })
   ));
```